# webdriver sampler getting the cookie value

Tags: jmeter

I want to simulate 20 different users (username+password combinations) into the same site for each user's unique auth token will create in the cookie. I want to extract the cookie value of every user and store it on the CSV file.

I wrote code in web driver sampler this code is working but every time when I executed the test cookie values are appended in the previous file.

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get('https://preprd.bcom3test.com/app/')
var username=WDS.vars.get('Username')
var password=WDS.vars.get('Password')
WDS.log.info(username)
WDS.log.info(password)
var ui=JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui) 
var wait=new ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser,120)
wait.until(ui.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//*[@data-autoid='lion-login']")))
var login = WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//*[@data-autoid='lion-login']"));
login.click();
wait.until(ui.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//*[@id='userNameInput']")))
var name = WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//*[@id='userNameInput']"));
name.sendKeys(username);
wait.until(ui.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//*[@id='passwordInput']")))
var pass = WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//*[@id='passwordInput']"));
pass.sendKeys(password);
wait.until(ui.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//*[@id='submitButton']")))
var submit = WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//*[@id='submitButton']"));
submit.click();
wait.until(ui.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//*[@id='idSIButton9']")))
var submit2 = WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//*[@id='idSIButton9']"));
submit2.click();
var cookie=WDS.browser.manage().getCookieNamed('MarcelAUTH').getValue();
WDS.log.info(cookie)
var output = new java.io.File('C:/Users/sapsharm/Desktop/auth.csv')
var newline = java.lang.System.lineSeparator()
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.writeStringToFile(output, cookie + newline, true)
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

expected CSV value should contain only new cookie values old values should be not present in the CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the code `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.writeStringToFile(output, cookie + newline, true)`

with below code

```
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.writeStringToFile(output, cookie + newline,null, false)
```

Refer [API Doc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#writeStringToFile(java.io.File,%20java.lang.String))

Method Description:

> public static void writeStringToFile(File file,String data,Charset
>   encoding,boolean append) throws IOException

```
Writes a String to a file creating the file if it does not exist.

Parameters:
    file - the file to write
    data - the content to write to the file
    encoding - the encoding to use, null means platform default
    append - if true, then the String will be added to the end of the file rather than overwriting
```